# retrieving records within a specified distance mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error when running this query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS COUNT,
       ((ACOS(SIN(
        (SELECT latitude
         FROM cities
         WHERE name = 'london' & country = 'gb')*PI()/180) * 
         SIN((cities.latitude)*PI()/180)+COS(                                                                                                      
 (SELECT latitude
  FROM cities
  WHERE name = 'london' && country = 'gb')*PI()/180)*COS((cities.latitude)*PI()/180)*COS((
(SELECT longitude
 FROM cities
 WHERE name = 'london' && country = 'gb')-
(cities.longitude))*PI()/180))*180/PI())*60*1.1515) AS distance
FROM tbl_products
LEFT JOIN members ON tbl_products.seller = members.id
LEFT JOIN business ON tbl_products.seller = business.bid
INNER JOIN cars ON tbl_products.prod_id = cars.prod_id
LEFT JOIN car ON cars.car = car.id
LEFT JOIN cities ON members.location = cities.id
LEFT JOIN regions ON cities.region = regions.code && cities.country = regions.country
WHERE tbl_products.title LIKE '%|mazda%' ESCAPE '|'
OR tbl_products.description LIKE '%|mazda%' ESCAPE '|' && regions.country = 'gb' HAVING distance <= '30';
```

Subquery returns more than 1 row.

I was just wondering how I go about retrieving records within a given distance.

Comment: Right now I'd say: messy code.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates exactly what it says. You're doing a subquery but it returns multiple rows, in a context where only one row is expected

```
SELECT count*(*) AS count, ACOS(SIN(...subselect here ...))
```

Hard to tell WHICH of the subselects you're doing is causing this, but you'll have to find which one, and get it to send back only ONE row. And since you're using the results in further function calls, you also have to make sure that only one FIELD is returned as well, e.g.

```
SELECT sin(select 1,2 from dual) from dual
```

would cause a related error.